# Is there any possible way for Data Replication?

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

Suppose my Master server have 10-15 database registered.
And on my slave server only have one or two of them.
So is there any possible way to sync between master and slave for that two databases only.

Cause while configuring data replication, there are settings for configure server only. 
So, Is there any configuration to specify databases which to replicate?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication.html

Comment: Getting, but how to implement? Any commands or configurations?

Comment: That's all in the link I provided

Comment: Yeah, I go through that article. But Is this possible to create publication for entire database. Cause In that article they created publication for particular tables.. I don't want particular table. I want entire db to be replicated. 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/logical-replication-quick-setup.html

Comment: If logical replication doesn't work for you, then you can look at Streaming Replication (https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Streaming_Replication).  There are many tutorials out there--if you are encountering a specific problem, please provide detail in your question, and we'll try our best to give you an answer

Comment: I did research on logical-replication. And I found that, Logical_replication only performs DML operation on Slave server, not performing DDL. So, If any new development done on master's server database. Then that will not replicated on Slaves. So, Is streaming replication will do both DML and DDL? and Thanks @richyen for your suggestions as well. I will do research on same.

Comment: Streaming Replication will replicate everything--DML + DDL

Comment: But if you only want 1-2 of your 10-15 databases replicated, you have to use Logical Replication.  Streaming Replication is all or nothing--exact clone of your Master-side database cluster

Comment: But Logical replication not replicating DDL! That's the main issue. That's why I am looking for another option.

Comment: https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/resources/pglogical/pglogical-docs/ 
I found this one as well. But I don't know how this will work. DML DDL or only DML.